# LDAP Server front-end Java library

Tags: java, server, ldap

I've been asked to look into adding an LDAP interface to an existing Java web application - that is, to make it possible for LDAP clients to connect to the application as if it's an LDAP server. I *could* write code to listen on a dedicated port and implement the LDAP protocol, and hook that into the existing database... but I'd have to understand the protocol first and then there are potential security issues if I write that from the ground up (not to mention the time it could take).

What I'm looking for is a library of existing code - something that handles the ports and protocols, and lets me focus on writing just the back end. There are plenty of client-side libraries out there, as you'd expect, but I've had no luck in finding something to help with server-side development. So the question is, does anyone here know of such a library that would help with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you will most probably find many more client implementations than server, however LDAP is a request response protocol, so with a bit of playing around you should be able to use the same classes and their serialization capabilities. Instead of sending the request you would be receiving it, and responding with the response you would otherwise expect from the client.

You could look at the Apache Directory. https://directory.apache.org/api/

It has an embedded directory server project as part of it, which claims to be extensible and embeddable in your application. https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/
So maybe that could be the answer to your needs.

Comment: A colleague mentioned this as a standalone server... but didn't mention that it's embeddable and extensible. This might well do what's needed.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not well documented. https://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/7-embedding-apacheds.html. So you might need to do a little fact finding. Maybe the people on its mailing list might be able to help.